# How could I ignore Retry-after header in response?

Tags: web-crawler, urllib3

I would like to ignore "Retry-after" header in response, and I use urllib3 to send a http request.

The code is below:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(timeout=urllib3.Timeout(connect=connecttimeout, read=readtimeout))
rq = http.request('GET', body=body, headers=headers, url='http://'+ url, redirect=2,retries=2)
rq.close()
```

How to allow redirect and retry ? I still want to use `http.request()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `util.retry.Retry`. It takes a `respect_retry_after_header` flag.

For example:

```
retries = Retry(connect=5, read=2, redirect=5, respect_retry_after_header=False)
http = PoolManager(retries=retries)
response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
```